# Is there any way to generate a standard response message to the request in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an api using Django DRF. The api is working pretty fine. But it is generating different responses, for different kinds of errors. Suppose, if I add a feature of user registration. I am handling some erros in serializers using `serializers.ValidationError` function. But this is changing the response for different errors. I only want the response in standard manner of `{"message": "reason for the error", "error": 1}`. I don't want to hard code it. I mean I have used in multiple functionalities, so I have to hard code all the places. Hence, is there any better solution, like adding a function to the serializer and generating the response from that ???

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, validators=[password_check], write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, validators=[password_check])
    Id = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, allow_blank=True)
    user_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username already chosen!')

        if len(username) < 8:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username min length is 8')
        return username

    def validate_email(self, email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Enter a valid email')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Email already chosen!')
        return email

    def validate(self, attrs):
        key = 0
        try:
            if models.Profile.objects.filter(userid=attrs['Id']).exists() and attrs['Id'] != '':
                raise serializers.ValidationError('UserId already chosen')
            if attrs['Id'] == '':
                key=1
        except KeyError:
                key=1

        if key == 1:
            if attrs['user_type'] != 'Admin' and attrs['user_type'] != 'AdminCoordinate':
                raise serializers.ValidationError("UserId can\'t be empty!")
            else:
                attrs['user_id'] = ''

        if attrs['password'] != attrs['confirm_password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Enter same passwords both the times!')
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'confirm_password', 'Id', 'user_type')
        read_only_fields = ('pk',)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way over this, at least not as easy as you want.

- You might be able to write a middleware to handle this but this might be still a little messy because you have to check for every single error in your response and override them. I don't really recommend doing this.
- You can also use Meta class for each serializer but still you have to add some codes for every serializer.

Example:

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeMode
        extra_kwargs = {"SomeField": {"error_messages": {"required": "This field can not be empty!"}}}
```

- You can write some validators yourself and use them to minimize your codes:
  [DRF - DOCS: Validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)

At the end, i think you will end up hard coding most of your validations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Navid2zp for the answer. That's really cool. But it can not handle all the exceptions. I went through the documentation and found a simple and generic way to handle all the exceptions. I wrote a simple code using which only one error can be displayed at a time rather than displaying multiple errors. This is how I coded it:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, content):

    response = exception_handler(exc, content) # Get the response Header.
    error = ''
    for key, value in response.data.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            error = value
        else:
            error = value[0]
        if key == 'non_field_errors':
            custom_response = {'message': error, 'error': 1}
        else:
            custom_response = {'message': key + ", " +  error, 'error': 1}
        break
    response.data = custom_response
    return response
```

I wrote a custom exception handler to display the messages, and also this class has to be added in the settings.py file inside `REST_FRAMEWORK`

```
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'project_name.utils.custom_exception_handler',
```